# Multilevel B-spline not working SAGA QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga, spline

I try performing a multilevel spline interpolation from the SAGA tool but I get an error message.

I have loaded a CSV consisting of 1500 points with latitude and longitude and elevation values. I'd like to interpolate the elevation with a spline method. However, I always get an error message and the protocol doesn't help at all.

The error in the protocol just says:

> the following layer couldn't be added.

```
processing.run("saga:bsplineapproximation",{'SHAPES':'delimitedtext://file:///C:/Users/49151/Documents/Kreuzkerpen1500csv.csv?type=csv&skipEmptyFields=Yes&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=export_res_1&yField=export_res_2&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=yes&subsetIndex=yes&watchFile=no',
                                            'FIELD':'export_res_3',
                                            'LEVEL':1,
                                            'TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX':None,
                                            'TARGET_USER_SIZE':100,
                                            'TARGET_USER_FITS':0,
                                            'TARGET_OUT_GRID':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
                                            )
```

[image: here are my parameters]

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the error message, as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is probably due to **zellengröße** (Cellsize) value if you are working with latitude and longitude expressed in degrees. For avoiding these errors, I used a value of 0.001 instead; as it can be observed in following image.

[image]

After click in Run, interpolation image was produced as expected (I only used 154 points but an error pop up when I used a value of 10).

[image]