# Interpolation Error: Saying it is completed but doesn't show up

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, interpolation, saga

- I am using processing toolbox Saga Interpolate (Cubic Spline) tool.

  [image]
- I then enter the details needed interpolating and click Run.

  [image]
- I get a task complete sign but don't get the file. In the Interpolate (cubic spline) log, I get an error message:

```
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.`
• C:/Users/JeromeLeray/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_qNvbww/21565185a87949cea46f7d0ecbe43397/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

[image]

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your cellsize is too high for used ESPG in degrees. Perhaps this question can be useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411295/multilevel-b-spline-not-working-saga-qgis/411444#411444

Comment: Thank you that worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the response given by @xunilk worked.

I also noticed I had to delete the output extent to make it work. See below the settings that made it work.

[image]